# Image Roll Overs for Instagram Feed

Tags: html, css, rollover

I'm building an app using the instagram API which pulls in certain instagrams. I'm trying to add a large heart roll over on each image which will eventually display the number of 'likes' the image has received. I'm stuck at this point as even though the hover works and the hearts display, they aren't in line with (and on top of) the images (see screengrab). I don't have any sort of div for each individual image as the code is just pulling in a list of images. I did however, create a div within the list to insert the rollover "on and "off" classes. [image: Screengrab of current view on hover]

Any help as to how to modify the code to make this work would be awesome. Thanks you!

```
{% for i in instagrams %}               
<ul>
    <li id= 'instagram'>
    <div class="roll">      
        <IMG class="on" img src='{{i[0]}}'>
        <IMG class="off" img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/321322043C0Y2g0R2K0g/smallerheart.jpg">
    </div>      
    <div id ="caption">{{i[1]}}</div>
</li>
```

{% endfor %}

```
img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: white;} 

.roll 
    .roll {width: 300px;}
    .roll {height: 300px;}
    .roll {background: blue;}
    .roll .on { display: block; }
    .roll .off { display: none; }
    .roll:hover .off { z-index:0; top:25px; left:8px; display: block; }
    .roll:hover .on {z-index:10; top:25px; left:8px; display: block; }                  

li#instagram {
    float: left;
    display: ;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a position on z-indexed elements like:

```
position: relative;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but I'm not sure I follow - I just want to heart to cover the image... I still need to state position relative?

Comment: z-index won't work on an element if a position for that element is not specified. See here:

http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

You can apply a position of relative, fixed or absolute, depending on what you are trying to accomplish.